# Differential structure on the cone

Tags: differential-geometry

Let's take $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the action of a cyclic group by standard rotations with center the origin. Can we put on the quotient a differential structure such that the projection is differentiable?

Comment: Try to google "orbifold".

Comment: Ok so for experts, why an orbifold is not in general a differential manifold?

Comment: The most obvious reason is that it's sometimes not even a topological manifold-e.g. the Kummer surface. I'm not actually sure whether one can give a smooth orbifold which is a topological manifold but not a smooth manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We have a homeomorphism $[z]\mapsto z^n$ of the quotient with $\mathbb{R}^2$ where our action is by the cyclic group of order $n$ and I identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{C}$. Under this chart, the projection map $z\mapsto z^n$ is smooth. So you're not forced to look at orbifolds for this action, although it may be a valuable perspective. The latter allows you to have charts be identity maps, instead of having to stretch the quotient space unnaturally to identify it with Euclidean space.